# getTopics equivalent for services (C++)

Tags: ros, c++, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using "getTopics" in ros/master.h to get a list of possible topics and their types.

There doesn't appear to be any equivalent for getting a list of services and types because services don't register their types with roscore. In the Python rosservice API, `rosservice list` uses rosgraph to send/recv a probe request over a raw TCP socket to get an individual service type.

Is there a built-in way of doing this with the C++ API? Do I need to resort to Boost.Python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102416/gettopics-equivalent-for-services-(c++)/) by [brianw1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1300/brianw1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's an example that uses Boost.Python to utilize rosservice:

[getServices](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7537252)

---

Originally posted by [brianw1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1300/brianw1/) with karma: 26 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0